# Set character format for a QML TextArea using QTextCursor

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create a very simple rich text editor component in QML. The requirements are that the user must be able to quickly format individual words inside a textbox separately. So for example, the user could press "Ctrl+B" in the middle of typing and from that point onward the text becomes bold, when the user press "Ctrl+B" again the subsequently typed text has a normal font weight:

So looking around I found that there is an [official example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-texteditor-example.html) provided by the Qt company to do this. So I extrapolated this to a very basic app:

```
// DocumentHandler.cpp
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickTextDocument>
#include <QTextCharFormat>

class DocumentHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQuickTextDocument *document READ document WRITE setDocument NOTIFY documentChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int cursorPosition READ cursorPosition WRITE setCursorPosition NOTIFY cursorPositionChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int selectionStart READ selectionStart WRITE setSelectionStart NOTIFY selectionStartChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int selectionEnd READ selectionEnd WRITE setSelectionEnd NOTIFY selectionEndChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool modified READ modified WRITE setModified NOTIFY modifiedChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool bold READ bold WRITE setBold NOTIFY boldChanged)
public:
    QQuickTextDocument *document() const;
    void setDocument(QQuickTextDocument *newDocument);

    int cursorPosition() const;
    void setCursorPosition(int newCursorPosition);

    int selectionStart() const;
    void setSelectionStart(int newSelectionStart);

    int selectionEnd() const;
    void setSelectionEnd(int newSelectionEnd);

    bool modified() const;
    void setModified(bool newModified);

    bool bold() const;
    void setBold(bool newBold);

signals:
    void documentChanged();

    void cursorPositionChanged();

    void selectionStartChanged();

    void selectionEndChanged();

    void modifiedChanged();

    void boldChanged();

private:
    void mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(const QTextCharFormat & format);
    void reset();

    QTextCursor textCursor() const;
    QTextDocument* textDocument() const;

    QQuickTextDocument * m_document = nullptr;

    int m_cursorPosition = -1;
    int m_selectionStart = 0;
    int m_selectionEnd = 0;
};

// DocumentHandler.cpp
#include "documenthandler.h"

#include <QTextCursor>

QQuickTextDocument *DocumentHandler::document() const
{
    return m_document;
}

void DocumentHandler::setDocument(QQuickTextDocument *newDocument)
{
    if (m_document == newDocument)
        return;
    if(m_document)
        m_document->textDocument()->disconnect(this);

    m_document = newDocument;
    if(m_document){
        QObject::connect(m_document->textDocument(), &QTextDocument::modificationChanged,
                        this, &DocumentHandler::modifiedChanged);
    }
    emit documentChanged();
}

int DocumentHandler::cursorPosition() const
{
    return m_cursorPosition;
}

void DocumentHandler::setCursorPosition(int newCursorPosition)
{
    if (m_cursorPosition == newCursorPosition)
        return;
    m_cursorPosition = newCursorPosition;
    reset();
    emit cursorPositionChanged();
}

int DocumentHandler::selectionStart() const
{
    return m_selectionStart;
}

void DocumentHandler::setSelectionStart(int newSelectionStart)
{
    if (m_selectionStart == newSelectionStart)
        return;
    m_selectionStart = newSelectionStart;
    emit selectionStartChanged();
}

int DocumentHandler::selectionEnd() const
{
    return m_selectionEnd;
}

void DocumentHandler::setSelectionEnd(int newSelectionEnd)
{
    if (m_selectionEnd == newSelectionEnd)
        return;
    m_selectionEnd = newSelectionEnd;
    emit selectionEndChanged();
}

bool DocumentHandler::modified() const
{
    return m_document && m_document->textDocument()->isModified();
}

void DocumentHandler::setModified(bool newModified)
{
    if (m_document)
        m_document->textDocument()->setModified(newModified);
}

void DocumentHandler::mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(const QTextCharFormat &format)
{
    QTextCursor cursor = textCursor();
    if (!cursor.hasSelection())
        cursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);

    cursor.mergeCharFormat(format);
}

void DocumentHandler::reset()
{
    emit boldChanged();
}

QTextCursor DocumentHandler::textCursor() const
{
    QTextDocument* doc = textDocument();
    if(!doc)
        return QTextCursor();
    QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(doc);
    if(m_selectionStart != m_selectionEnd){
        cursor.setPosition(m_selectionStart);
        cursor.setPosition(m_selectionEnd, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
    }
    else{
        cursor.setPosition(m_cursorPosition);
    }
    return cursor;
}

QTextDocument *DocumentHandler::textDocument() const
{
    return m_document ? m_document->textDocument() : nullptr;
}

bool DocumentHandler::bold() const
{
    auto cursor = textCursor();
    if(cursor.isNull())
        return false;
    return cursor.charFormat().fontWeight() == QFont::Bold;
}

void DocumentHandler::setBold(bool newBold)
{
    QTextCharFormat format;
    format.setFontWeight(newBold ? QFont::Bold : QFont::Normal);
    mergeFormatOnWordOrSelection(format);
    emit boldChanged();
}


// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import DocumentHandler 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: "lightpink"

    header: ToolBar {
        id: appToolbar
        ToolButton {
            text: "Bold"
            checkable: true
            checked: documentHandler.bold
            onClicked: {
                documentHandler.bold = !documentHandler.bold
            }
        }
    }

    DocumentHandler {
        id: documentHandler
        document: textInput.textDocument
        cursorPosition: textInput.cursorPosition
        selectionStart: textInput.selectionStart
        selectionEnd: textInput.selectionEnd
    }
    TextArea {
        id: textInput
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.pixelSize: 30
        wrapMode: TextEdit.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere
        focus: true
        selectByMouse: true
        persistentSelection: true
        textFormat: Qt.RichText
    }
}
```

If you try to run this app, type something like "hello" and the press the "Bold" button the app correctly makes the "hello" bold. However, there is a problem I'm struggling to get past:
if you click on the button when the textarea is empty, then typing doesn't give you bold text. In fact, it seems that it is not possible to change the font weight of the textarea prior to having some text in it. Also, if you type a word, then press space and then click the button: nothing happens.
Anyone got any clue on what's the root cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Hi, the [mergeCharFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#mergeCharFormat) function of the cursor will only *merge a new format if a selection is made*, and a selection will only be made *if the cursor is over a word*.

Thus, no character format will merge to the cursor if there is no selection.

Comment: @SMR I think the documentation doesn't say that: "Merges the cursor's current character format with the properties described by format modifier. ". Thus, if there is no selection, the current character format where the cursor is located will be merged with the given modifier.
Anyway, even if you use QTextCursor::setCharFormat() the issue persists.